# Knockout ObservableArray

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I am knew to knockout and have a question about how to do some conditional binding. I have a dropdown input that shows and hides other inputs depending upon the option that is selected. I have that working but I am having a problem when I load the page after the page has already been posted previously. I am able to GET the dropdown inputs that was previously selected and posted but the binding that takes place (showing and hiding) of the other inputs is not triggered. Please see below:

```
<script>
function ViewModel() {
  this.selectedPet = ko.observable();
  var petArray = ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"];
  this.petOptions = ko.observableArray(petArray);
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
</script>


<form>
  <select data-bind="options: petOptions, value: selectedPet" asp-for="Pets">
  </select>

  <input data-bind="visible: petOptions() === "Dog" asp-for="DogFood" />
  <input data-bind="visible: petOptions() === "Cat" asp-for="CatFood" />
  <input data-bind="visible: petOptions() === "Fish" asp-for="FishFood" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. I need to set the initial observable value to the value that was posted.

```
var onLoadPet = "@Model.Pet.Value";
function ViewModel() {
  this.selectedPet = ko.observable(onLoadPet);
}
```